# How to step into a function with gdb ddebugger when that function is located in another c program that is located in another folder?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I have an existing 'c' code written by a researcher and I want to debug it. The project is compiled using MAkE. I am trying to debug using gdb debugger.
suppose 'A' folder contains '`myproject.c`', '`myproject`', `MAKEFILE` and some subfolders B,C,D etc.
Now I debug the file gdb myproject. I created breakpoint at a function1. This `function 1` is located in a file `x.c` in folder B. When I pass `step` command, it is executing the whole function but I want to see it line by line.

Comment: Did you compile it with a -g flag?

Comment: The Make File already has -g flag included

Comment: It will be hard to help you without any code. Show us the code and the lines you write to compile it (from the makefile). https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I pass step command, it is executing the whole function but I want to see it line by line.

This means that `x.c` is compiled without debug info (without `-g` flag).

> The Make File already has -g flag included

What the `Makefile` has is somewhat irrelevant. What matters is the command line that `make` constructs to compile `x.c`.

Run `make clean all`. That should (assuming proper `Makefile`) rebuild the entire program, recompiling `x.c`. Now *look* at the command line used to compile `x.c`. It will not have `-g` option. You'll need to modify the `Makefile` so it does.